# CAML query not working

Tags: caml-query, date-time

I have written following CAML query to Retrieve items which are due in 7 days, It doesn't seems to be working, Please let me know what I missed ?

```
string internalEndDate = web.Lists["List Name"].Fields["Next End date"].InternalName;

<Where>
  <AND>
  <Leq>
   <FieldRef Name ='" + internalEndDate + "'/> 
   <Value Type ='DateTime'>" + System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) + "</Value>
  </Leq> 

  </AND>
 </Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='" + internalClosure + "' Ascending='False' />
</OrderBy>";
```

The above query does't seem to be working, Also how can I add along with this condition, the data has to be greater than or equal to today. Thanks!!

UPDATE : (As Per Sven Gillis advise, Worked !!)

```
string Iso8601DateTime = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
string Iso8601Today = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);


<Where>
      <AND>
      <Leq>
       <FieldRef Name ='" + internalEndDate + "'/> 
       <Value Type ='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + Iso8601DateTime  + "</Value>
      </Leq> 
       <Geq>
       <FieldRef Name ='" + internalEndDate + "'/> 
       <Value Type ='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>>" + Iso8601Today + "</Value>
      </Geq> 
      </AND>
 </Where>
  <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='" + internalClosure + "' Ascending='False' />
  </OrderBy>";
```

And used,  tag to filter the date greater than today!!

Got It Worked !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to convert your DateTime object to a ISO8601 format. You can use the [SPUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) class. I always use the U2U Caml Query builder to test my queries.

Comment: I guess U2U is only for 2007 and not for 2010 !!

Comment: No, you can still use this tool, but you need to connect with the webservices - otherwise it won't work...

Comment: I think you need to install the client app. Did u try downloading and installing from this link? - http://www.u2u.net/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

Comment: I even tried with this, query.Query = @"<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name ='" + internalClosure + "'/> <Value Type ='DateTime'> <Today OffsetDays='7'> </Value></Leq></Where>"; Now getting a SP exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Comment: Thanks, Got it worked, Updated my question to include changes !!

Answer (score 4):

You can even pass the date in the format yyyy-MM-dd ... :)

Comment: Hi Paddy I am using this code to pass the date, System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), Now how will I make it that way ?

Comment: I even tried with this, query.Query = @"<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name ='" + internalClosure + "'/> <Value Type ='DateTime'> <Today OffsetDays='7'> </Value></Leq></Where>"; Now getting a SP exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Comment: hi... you can make it as... System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).toString("yyyy-MM-dd")...

Answer (score 4):

Sven Gillis has the correct answer that the DateTime object needs to be in the ISO format required.

I want to elaborate on why your code specifically is not working as you expected.  You are concatenating the DateTime object (the output of DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)) with other string objects.  This will call the default .[ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx)() method of DateTime.  This will display the date/time in the current culture of the process the code is running in (ie. the SharePoint server).

Comment: Thanks, then what now I should do with my date ?

Comment: I even tried with this,  `query.Query = @"<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name ='" + internalClosure + "'/> <Value Type ='DateTime'> <Today OffsetDays='7'> </Value></Leq></Where>";` Now getting a SP exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Comment: Thanks, RUSSELL got it worked see the updated question !!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the date should be in Sortable DateTi­me Pattern like "2011-12-26T00:00:00". Try this String.Format("{0:s}", Date)

Comment: Thanks, Shankar Got It worked!! Plz see the updated answer!!