# How to reterive list item values using CAML query?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query, sharepoint-addin

I have one Date and time column and text colum. I need to retrieve list item value based on this both column using CAML query..

For ex:

Columname---> Date  value for date would be-6/1/2013 and another date would be 6/3/2013

Columnname-> Team Value for Team would be -A

I could not able to install U2u Builder in my machince.
My CAML query as mentioned below

```
<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>PP</Value></Eq><Gt><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>6/1/2013</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>6/2/2013</Value></Lt></Eq></And></Where>
```

Please can any one give Correct CAML query for this condition. i am going to get the values in javascript.

#

```
<script type="text/javascript">ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js");
        function MainFunction() {
            var myQueryString = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>PP</Value></Eq><Gt><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>6/1/2013</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>6/2/2013</Value></Lt></Eq></And></Where>";
            var myContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); ;
            var myWeb = myContext.get_web();
            var myList = myWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("as");
            var myQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            myQuery.set_viewXml(myQueryString);
            myItems = myList.getItems(myQuery);
            myContext.load(myItems, 'Include(ID,Title,Tower)');
            myContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, GetListDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(
this, GetListDataFail));
            //alert('Query started, but not yet finished!'); 
        }
        function GetListDataFail(sender, args) {
            // Show error message
            alert('GetListDataFail() failed:' + args.get_message());
        }
        function GetListDataSuccess(sender, args) {
            var currListItemCount = myItems.get_count();
            //alert(currListItemCount + ' Items found!'); 
            var currItemEnumerator = myItems.getEnumerator();
            var currItemDetails = '';
            // Loop through all items 
            while (currItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                // Get current item 
                var currItem = currItemEnumerator.get_current();
                // Concatenate values 
                if (currItemDetails == "")
                    currItemDetails = currItem.get_item("Tower");
                else
                    currItemDetails = currItemDetails + ';' + currItem.get_item("Tower");
            }
            // Show details 
            //alert(currItemDetails); 
            callCombo(currItemDetails);
        }
        function addValuetoCombo(txtvalue, ddl) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = txtvalue;
            option.value = txtvalue;
            try {
                ddl.add(option, null); //Standard 
            } catch (error) {
                alert('error');
                ddl.add(option); // IE only
            }
        }
        function callCombo(msg) {
            var str_array = msg.split(';');
            var combo = document.getElementById("ddlbox");
            //alert(msg);
            for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                // Trim the excess whitespace.
                //alert(str_array[i]);
                var objText = str_array[i];
                // Add data to dropdown
                addValuetoCombo(objText, combo);
                //alert(i);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all - you have aמ unnecessary closing tag `</Eq>` at the end.

Also, [you can not put more than 2 conditions in the AND or OR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204309/1206300),

In addition, [You have to convert your DateTime object to a ISO8601 format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/25875/10098).

So your CAML should look like this:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Team' />
      <Value Type='Text'>PP</Value>
    </Eq>
    <And>
      <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name='Date' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(FromDate)</Value>
      </Gt>
      <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name='Date' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(ToDate)</Value>
      </Lt>
    </And>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: I have try with your above code, it displaying all list item values from the list.

Comment: I would recommend you to run any of the conditions separately and see which one is the problem.

Comment: Hi For Date field it is reterving all items from the list...

Comment: Even when you run only one of them without the other conditions?

Comment: Yes..It is reterving all items from the list...

Comment: Please try `IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'` - with uppercase letters.

Comment: It also does not works..

Comment: So maybe there is a problem with the column name?
Do you use the Internal Name?

Comment: Just a note: as the OP asked for a JavaScript solution, and the SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime method is available only in .NET / C#, one shoud use rather the toISOString method instead to convert the date to a standard ISO 8601 format, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString