# How to pass a string(date) in a caml query to get listitem based on datetime type of field

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

I want to pass a string(date) in a caml query to get listitem based on datetime type of field.
I am not getting any value in return. Please suggest. Below is my code:

```
` private SP.ListItem FindListItem(List selectedList, Field field, string value, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        SP.ListItem listItem = null;
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        if (field.TypeAsString == "DateTime")
        {
            DateTime datevalue = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=" + field.InternalName + @"/><Value Type=" + field.TypeAsString + @">" + datevalue + @"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";                               

        SP.ListItemCollection items = selectedList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load<SP.ListItemCollection>(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        if (items.Count > 0)
            listItem = items[0];

        return listItem;
    }`
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert your DateTime object to a ISO8601 format. You can use the [SPUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) class.

Example:

```
string datevalue = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(value));
```

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/25875/9345)

---

As far as Client-Side Object Model (CSOM), versus Server Side,

**Server-Side**

```
string datevalue = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(value));
```

**Client-Side**

You would need to use the string formatter,

```
string datevalue = Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

---

As far as the performance optimizations, suggested by the other individual, there are some suggestions, at the following [page](http://mosstouch.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-client-object-model_3.html?_sm_au_=iVVT1q0NQ5R3Dk1s) using CSOM, Point #5, on how to reduce the number of round trips to the server, and increase performance.

Comment: Is it possible to use SPUtility in Client Object Model?

Comment: I had updated answer, immediately following your comment yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert your DateTime object to a ISO8601 format using [SPUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) class. and then pass it to Caml query.

```
string Iso8601Today = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
```

Replace DateTime.Now with your "value".

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/25875/9345)

Comment: Is it possible to use SPUtility in Client Object Model?

Comment: You can use [Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx) Class in CSOM. If you want to achieve the same date in CSOM then, you should use string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

Answer (score 0):

get listitems without query , clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); after do your limitation by converting your string to date. this can be reduce performance.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a function to convert a date to ISO Date.

```
function ISODateString(d){
  function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
      + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}
```

Then you use like that:

```
var desde = ISODateString(Pdesde);
var hasta = ISODateString(Phasta);
```

And the CAML is:

```
'<Query><Where><And><Leq><FieldRef Name="Fecha"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">' + hasta + '</Value></Leq><Geq><FieldRef Name="Fecha"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">' + desde + '</Value></Geq></And></Where></Query>'
```